# How to report usernames by date_joined?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to write a report where usernames must be listed grouped by date(date_joined)?

For example:

2015-12-03
    - User1
    - User2

2015-12-04
    - User3
    - User4

How do I approach this problem?

I tried https://coderwall.com/p/z126aa/django-count-user-growth-each-month but it gives only the count but what I need is usernames by date.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you want to output this report in the template. In which case the easiest thing is just to get all Users sorted by date, then use the `regroup` tag in the template to do the grouping.

View:

```
users = User.objects.all().order_by('date_joined')
```

Template:

```
{% regroup users by date_joined as user_date_list %}

<ul>
{% for date in user_date_list %}
    <li>{{ date.grouper }}
    <ul>
        {% for item in date.list %}
          <li>{{ item.username }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```